# Process org.freedesktop.secrets received signal 6

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, gnome-keyring

My problem is, `gnome-keyring` is not starting properly, producing the error in title. When I open Geary, it shows this error in the terminal. When I start `gnome-keyring` with `gnome-keyring-daemon --start`, it says:

```
** Message: 17:01:04.371: couldn't connect to dbus session bus: Error spawning command line "dbus-launch --autolaunch=dc2f47b8e70843788ceb4ea9dcc3b094 --binary-syntax --close-stderr": Child process exited with code 1
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/root/.cache/keyring-JXAR60
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/root/.cache/keyring-JXAR60/ssh
```

When I run the command specified in the above error, I get:

```
Autolaunch requested, but X11 support not compiled in.
Cannot continue.
```

How can I fix this?

My system is Arch Linux, all packages up to date.

thanks Stephen for edit, just im russian and my english grammar is bad

Comment: still waiting, but i can use keepassxc instead of gnome keyring, which seems working

Comment: [KeePassXC Secrets Service](https://c3pb.de/blog/keepassxc-secrets-service.html) also turned out to be a good solution for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer. Use KeePassXC instead of gnome keyring. It is working for me without any problem